# OpenLDAP admin password after installation

Tags: linux, authentication, ubuntu, ldap, ubuntu-14.04

I installed an openLDAP server on Ubuntu 14.04 and set the admin password during the installation. But now I'm not able to connect with this password. cn=admin exists because I can see it when iI login as anonymous user. What can I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can set the admin password with

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure slapd
```

to a new one.

then you need to login with the full credentials of the admin user and the domain, like:

```
cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com
```

Answer (score 3):

Run the search

```
ldapsearch -H ldap:// -x -s base -b "" -LLL "+"
```

find the dc=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx  and then try to run a command, for example:

```
ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=ldapadm,dc=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx" -f /etc/openldap/slapd.d/xxxxx.ldif
```

many times is not the password the problem